# libpcap disable monitor mode (C, macOS)

Tags: c, macos, libpcap

I have a function that enables monitor mode for a WiFi device on macOS using libpcap. This works, but currently the only way to set the WiFi device back to managed mode is to exit the process. I would like to set the WiFi device to managed mode while allowing the process to continue. As far as I can tell, this can't be done with libpcap. How would I set the WiFi device back to managed mode (potentially using the CoreWLAN API in Objective-C?)?

```c
pcap_t *enable_monitor(char *dev) {
    wifi_disassociate();

    char error_buffer[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    pcap_t *handle;
    int result;

    handle = pcap_create(dev, error_buffer);
    if (handle == NULL) {
        printf("failed to create a handle: %s\n",
               error_buffer);
        return NULL;
    }
    result = pcap_set_rfmon(handle, 1);
    if (result != 0) {
        printf("failed to set pcap rfmon: %s (%s)\n",
               pcap_statustostr(result),
               pcap_geterr(handle));
        return NULL;
    }
    result = pcap_activate(handle);
    if (result != 0) {
        printf("failed to activate handle: %s (%s)\n",
               pcap_statustostr(result),
               pcap_geterr(handle));
        return NULL;
    }
    //pcap_close(handle);
    return handle;
}
```

Edit:
Setting the second argument to `cap_set_rfmon` to 0 does not seem to set the device to managed mode, it just doesn't set it to monitor mode.

```c
int disable_monitor(pcap_t *handle) {
    int result;
    result = pcap_set_rfmon(handle, 0);
    if (result != 0) {
        printf("failed to set pcap rfmon: %s (%s)\n",
               pcap_statustostr(result),
               pcap_geterr(handle));
        return 1;
    }
    pcap_close(handle);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    char *dev = find_wifi_device();
    pcap_t *handle = enable_monitor(dev);
    sleep(5);
    int status = disable_monitor(handle);
    printf("Status: %d\n", status);
    for (;;)
        sleep(100);
}
```

This results in:

```
failed to set pcap rfmon: The setting can't be changed after the pcap_t is activated (can't perform  operation on activated capture)
Status: 1
```

Comment: Doesn't the second argument to `pcap_set_rfmon()` indicate whether monitor mode should be on or off? So calling it with `0` should turn it off. Are you saying that doesn't work?

Comment: It didn't work when I tried. https://linux.die.net/man/3/pcap_set_rfmon says that "If rfmon is non-zero, monitor mode will be set, otherwise it will not be set." I'm not sure whether that means that if it is 0 it is actually set to managed mode or if it just doesn't set monitor mode. I'll experiment some more.

Comment: "not be set" means off. What else could it mean?

Comment: I poked around in [libpcap's source code](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/blob/d16d425fc38a43f4a798630036d110445c81ee37/pcap-bpf.c#L1957), it just doesn't enable monitor mode if `pcap_set_rfmon` is called with 0. It doesn't actually disable it. The library is for packet capture, I would guess that it is set to 0 to capture packets without putting the WiFi device into monitor mode.

Comment: Why are you calling `pcap_create` et. al. in disable VS passing the handle from enable? What is inverse of `wifi_disassoisociate`?

Comment: @CraigEstey You're right, I just copied the `enable_monitor` function and changed 1 to 0, but I should have used the existing handle. I've updated my question. It won't let me set rfmon to 0. `wifi_disassoisociate` just disconnects from any routers, and isn't applicable while in monitor mode.

Comment: From `pcap_set_rfmon`, it sets the mode. But, it only takes effect "when activated" (i.e. `pcap_activate`. So, you may have to close the handle and open a fresh instance, then do `pcap_set_rfmon` with 0. What is the _default_ mode? I guessing promiscuous mode, so to reset monitor mode, you may have to use `pcap_set_promisc` instead of or in conjunction with the _second_ `pcap_set_rfmon` call

Comment: @CraigEstey That worked. Thank you. `pcap_set_promisc` works without a second `pcap_set_rfmon`. Since there are no answers, should I post one myself, leave the question open or just delete it?

Comment: @BenjaminMickler I did some source code snooping and posted a slightly expanded answer.

Comment: "linux.die.net/man/3/pcap_set_rfmon says" Note that macOS has the libpcap man pages, too, although Apple doesn't provide the current versions online any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefaced by my top comments ...

From `man pcap_set_rfmon`, it sets the mode. But, it only takes effect "when activated" (i.e. `pcap_activate`).

Further, if called on an *already* activated handle, the call returns the `PCAP_ERROR_ACTIVATED` error.

I've looked through the `libpcap` source code and ...

Once a connection has been activated, I can find *no* `pcap_*` call that will "deactivate" it. So, we may have to close the handle and open a fresh instance.

Also, AFAICT, do `pcap_set_rfmon` with 0 clears a flag (e.g. `pcap->opt.rfmon`). But, with a new instance (i.e. *before* calling `pcap_activate`), this should already be clear, so this is an effective no-op.

The *interface* is already in a given mode from the first `pcap_activate` call. Generally, it doesn't "reset" if we call `pcap_close` (*Note:* For *some* interfaces, the interface *will* be marked to reset upon `pcap_close` but we probably can't rely on that in general).

What is the default mode? I'm guessing promiscuous mode, so to reset monitor mode, we may have to use `pcap_set_promisc` instead.

> That worked. Thank you. `pcap_set_promisc` works without a second `pcap_set_rfmon`. –
> Benjamin Mickler

Answer (score 1):

If you *only* care about macOS, then:

The way to enable monitor mode on macOS is to use the `BIOCSDLT` ioctl on the file descriptor for the raw BPF device (which you can get using the `pcap_fileno()` call on the `pcap_t *`) to set the link-layer type to `DLT_IEEE802_11_RADIO` (which, as far as I know, all Wi-Fi adapter drivers on macOS support), and to disable it is to use the same ioctl to set it to `DLT_EN10MB`.  (That's what libpcap uses.)

See the bpf(4) man page for details on that ioctl.

Note that this will *NOT* work on any other operating system.  They all have their own different ways to set monitor mode.

Note that if you're capturing traffic on the BPF device, once you change the link-layer type, the packets that arrive after the change will have *different link-layer headers*.

Note also that, at least with drivers for the adapters on newer Macs, and with newer versions of macOS, attempting to go into monitor mode will prevent packets from being captured unless you somehow force the adapter to disconnect from the network.  (That's what the "Sniffer" menu item in "Wireless Diagnostics" does - it disconnects you from your network, and may do other magic, and then fires up tcpdump with the `-I` option to capture in monitor mode, writing out capture files.)